# Android Exit own Launcher App

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest, kiosk

I created a small custom Launcher App with setting

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

in my Android Manifest. But if I want to exit to the normal Launcher, how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First clear defaults for you launcher using

```
this.getPackageManager().clearPackagePreferredActivities(this.getPackageName());
```

Then exit from your activity

```
finish();
```

Then simulate home button using below, it'll show the home selecter

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

For new readers: android.intent.category.MONKEY intent.

in the android source code launcher manifest there are these intent-filters:

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
</intent-filter>
```

your "home screen" activity manifest should contain only these:

```
 <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
```

So, to lauanch the android Launcher call this from your activity:

```
 Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory("android.intent.category.MONKEY");
        startActivity(startMain);
```